# How to burn bootloader/program an ATMega 328P with an external crystal 8 MHz oscilator?

Tags: atmega328, oscillator-clock

I need to program a ATMega328P on a breadboard, running on an external crystal at 8 MHz.

All of the guides I can find either use the arduino environment and describe a 16 MHz config, or using the 8 MHz internal oscillator - which is too inaccurate for this project.

How do I do this?  Configure the chip to run at 8 MHz and upload the program?

Comment: why don't you use the internal 8Mhz crystal?

Comment: Because I'm using serial communication with another device - the internal 8Mhz crystal is only rated as accurate within 10% at 25 degrees C.  Serial communication tolerates an error of about half this.

Comment: There is no such thing as an internal 8 MHz crystal, just an 8 MHz RC oscillator.

Comment: I accept the correction that the on chip device isn't a crystal.  Doesn't change the reason I can't use it :)

Comment: you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Edited to make question explicit.

Comment: Because you edited this in once more (and I corrected it): The unit is spelled "MHz", not "Mhz".

Comment: Solution used an arduino, but I'd happily accept (and prefer) a lower level solution.  Even so, surely that's a vote to move, not vote to close?

Comment: *why don't you use the internal 8Mhz crystal?* There is no "internal crystal". the internal oscillator is a rc oscillator. fairly imprecise and not as stable as a crystal oscillator.

Answer (score 2):

myself as of 3 hours ago.

1. Get an arduino or similar, install the ArduinoISP sketch
2. Connect the two as described [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard).
3. Change the board to Arduino Pro or Pro Mini, Processor to 3.3V, 8Mhz, Programmer: Arduino as ISP
4. Hit burn bootloader button
5. Load up the sketch that you want on the device
6. Without changing anything, use "Upload using programmer"
7. Remove arduino, fix wiring changes required to use as programmer

Committed to Electronics Stackexchange  for posterity.  Or so I can find it when I forget next time...